# Find the last time a record was used

Tags: sql, time, record

I have a database that is used at a restaurant from which I am trying to generate some information.  I want to see a list of all the items used in the restaurant and the last time they were used.  In doing this I hope to be able to present the restaurant a list of all the items in their system that can be inactivated and removed from their system to clean things up.

**Relevant Tables (Aliases):**  Food_Tkt (t); Food_Tkt_Item (i); Food_Selection (s)
**Relevant Fields:** t.Tkt_Key; t.Tkt_Date; i.Tkt_Key; i.Selection_Key; s.Selection_Key; s.Selection_Name

Food_Tkt is inner joined on Food_Tkt_Item on t.Tkt_Key = i.Tkt_Key.  Food_Tkt_Item is inner joined on Food_Selection on i.Selection_Key = s.Selection_Key.

I want the query to show the Selection Key, the Selection Name, and the last time it was used, but I just can't seem to get it right.  Please, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to be as clear as I could, but anymore information is needed for clarification let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your query that isn't working?  What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that a good way to do so would be selecting the fields you want, as you said: Selection Key, Selection Name ordering the Tkt_Date using the DESC clausule... I believe that should get you the information you're looking for.

```
SELECT s.Selection_Key, s.Selection_Name, MIN(t.Tkt_Date) FROM Food_Selection s
INNER JOIN Food_Tkt_Item i ON i.Selection_Key = s.Selection_Key
INNER JOIN Food_Tkt t ON t.Tkt_Key = i.Tkt_Key
ORDER BY t.Tkt_Date DESC
```

Or something like that. :)

PS. You can try and replace the MAX, depending on the result you want.

Comment: I had gotten that far, but what I really want is a query that returns one record for each record on Food_Selection showing the most recent date it was sold.

Comment: Oh! I see, then I believe you could put a MAX(date) before the field, that way it's quite certain that it will only get the last row within that kind of information... you could also use MIN(date), once you get the parameters right.

Try it and come back :D

Answer (score 1):

I could be something like :

```
SELECT S.Selection_Key, S.Selection_Name, T.Tkt_Date
FROM Food_Selection S, Food_Tkt T, Food_Tkt_Item I
WHERE
T.Tkt_Key = I.Tkt_Key
AND
I.Selection_Key = S.Selection_Key
ORDER BY T.Tkt_Date DESC
```